# How to make a JQuery Script Only Fire Once

Tags: jquery, reload

I have a JQuery script that selects the right radio button on a wordpress-plugin form and then hits the update button. The problem is that the update button reloads the script causing an infinite loop.

How can I make sure the script only does its job once?? This is the code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
       $('input[value="Yes"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
       $(".update-button").trigger('click');
    }
 );
```

Comment: So the update button submits the form, I take it?

Comment: can we see the markup  of `.update-button`?

Comment: Document.ready will always run when the document loads. That is what it is for. What are you trying to get the page to do? Submit something when a user is redirected there?

Comment: Well, the wordpress plugin handle's the form, and does calculation. The problem is that the default setting of the 2 radio buttons doesn't suite my situation. I needed the other button to be selected and do the corresponding calculations. That al works now. Only now i have to make it stop after it did it's job

Answer (score 2):

One option is to store a value when you click update in an area that won't be lost when the page is refreshed. When the page is refreshed, then check to see if that value is still there. If it is, don't re-execute the script. I chose to use `localStorage` for my example, but cookies work just as well:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(!localStorage.updated) {
        $('input[value="Yes"]').attr('checked', 'checked');

        $(".update-button").trigger('click');
        localStorage.updated = "true";
    }
});
```

Comment: Seems good Elliot. But i'm wondering (this might be a dumb question..), but if the localStorage is set to true what's gonna happen when the next person visit's my site? I guess i have to store the information by the user of my site. You mentioned about cookies, how would that work? (never worked with cookies before..)

Comment: @Benno: `localStorage` is separate for each browser, so it has the same effect as a cookie.